# HTMLDocument getElementById for a custom control returns null, why, and is there a different way to access it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following in an aspx page inside a body tag:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
 <customControl:menu id="Menu1" runat="server">
 </customControl:menu>
</form>
```

And from a different aspx page I have this javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function testFunction(args, name) {
  alert(top.frames[0].document);      //gives me [object HTMLDocument]
  alert(top.frames[0].document.getElementById("Form1"));  //gives me [object HTMLFormElement]
  alert(top.frames[0].document.getElementById("Menu1"));      //gives me [null]
 }
</script>
```

Why is the third alert giving me null? (The `menu` is a control with an `ascx` extension)

Thanks,
Voodoo

Comment: Whichever page renders both of the above snippets in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quote from an article I recently wrote: [Take Control Of Web Control ClientID Values in ASP.NET 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203215/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx)

> Each server-side Web control in an
>   ASP.NET Web Forms application has an
>   ID property that identifies the Web
>   control and is the name by which the
>   Web control is accessed in the
>   code-behind class. When rendered into
>   HTML, the Web control turns its
>   server-side ID value into a
>   client-side id attribute. Ideally,
>   there would be a one-to-one
>   correspondence between the value of
>   the server-side ID property and the
>   generated client-side id, but in
>   reality things aren't so simple. By
>   default, the rendered client-side id
>   is formed by taking the Web control's
>   ID property and prefixed it with the
>   ID properties of its *naming
>   containers*. In short, a Web control
>   with an ID of txtName can get rendered
>   into an HTML element with a
>   client-side id like
>   ctl00_MainContent_txtName.
>
> This default translation from the
>   server-side ID property value to the
>   rendered client-side id attribute can
>   introduce challenges when trying to
>   access an HTML element via JavaScript,
>   which is typically done by id, as the
>   page developer building the web page
>   and writing the JavaScript does not
>   know what the id value of the rendered
>   Web control will be at design time.

The Web control's client-side id value can be determined at runtime via the Web control's ClientID property. This is why others have suggested using <%=Menu1.ClientID%> in place of a hard-coded id name.

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0 you have more control over how Web controls render their ID property into a client-side id via the Client. Namely, you can set the Menu's ClientIDMode property to Static to ensure that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the server-side ID property and the client-side id attribute (but you must be careful using this approach).

For more information refer to:

- [ASP.NET 4.0 ClientID Overview](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx)
- [Take Control Of Web Control ClientID Values in ASP.NET 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203215/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx)

Happy Programming!

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. However I am still getting an error when using using the `<%=Menu1.ClientID%>` ; The error I get is `Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Menu1' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: In your description you said that you had the control (Menu1) in one ASP.NET page and the JavaScript in another ASP.NET page. (Do you mean a User Control? A Master Page?) Anywho, that's the reason why you can't reference Menu1 - it's in a different "page."

Answer (score 2):

The `id` that is being output by asp.net is probably not `Menu1` - asp.net normally concatenates the container names to the control `id`, to avoid duplicate `id`s in a page.

Use the [`ClientId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property to get the `id` that will be output to the browser:

```
alert(top.frames[0].document.getElementById("<%:Menu1.ClientId%>")); // .NET 4 syntax
alert(top.frames[0].document.getElementById("<%=Menu1.ClientId%>")); // .NET 2/3/3.5 syntax
```

Comment: 'Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Menu1' does not exist in the current context
'  Any ideas? (using .NET 3.5 Framework)

Comment: @Oded - No I didn't remove anything. The page where the customControl is getting called has this on the top... `<%@ Register TagPrefix="customControl" TagName="Menu" Src="../../Controls/Menu.ascx" %>`

Comment: @VoodooChild - Take another look at your aspx page, perhaps do a `build clean -> build all`. If there is a `Menu1` control on the page, this should work.

Comment: Still doesn't work; `alert(top.frames[0].document.getElementById("Menu1"));` gives me null; and `alert(top.frames[0].document.getElementById("<%=Menu1.ClientId%>"));` gives the compilation error!!! I wonder if it has anything to do with the `TagPrefix`?

Comment: Also, just want to make it clear that the `Menu1` is on a different aspx page than where the js function is, could that be the issue? how can reference that element from a different page?

Comment: @VoodooChild - If it is on a separate page, how do you expect your JS to find it?

Answer (score 1):

When an element is inside a custom control or other such container (e.g. a master page), ASPX creates an id such that the element can have a unique ID on the page (by adding the container name to the element id, etc.).   Therefore, you can't use the id that you gave the element in your javascript; it's actual id will be different.

Within the aspx code you can get access to that runtime id by using the ClientId property.  Alternately, you can use jQuery and use some other selector (e.g. a name, class, etc.) to identify the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 alert(top.frames[0].document.getElementById("<% = Menu1.ClientID %>"));
```

If you're using 4.0, you can add

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

to force the ID to remain unchanged.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx